# Request.newMeRequest never returns

Tags: java, android, facebook

I am using Request.newMeRequest() to get a users email and name via facebook login, I am using the following block of code.

This code exists on an activity called SignUp which the user navigates too from the MainActivity.

My problem is that after entering email and password, and succesfully granting facebook permissions the app returns to the MainActivity state and the rest of the function (the onCompleted section) never gets triggered.

```
private void performFacebookLogin()
{
    Log.d("FACEBOOK", "performFacebookLogin");
    final Session.NewPermissionsRequest newPermissionsRequest = new Session.NewPermissionsRequest(this, Arrays.asList("email"));
    Session openActiveSession = Session.openActiveSession(this, true, new Session.StatusCallback()
    {
        @Override
        public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception)
        {
            Log.d("FACEBOOK", "call");
            if (session.isOpened() && !isFetching)
            {
                Log.d("FACEBOOK", "if (session.isOpened() && !isFetching)");
                isFetching = true;
                session.requestNewReadPermissions(newPermissionsRequest);
                Request getMe = Request.newMeRequest(session, new GraphUserCallback()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response)
                    {
                        Log.d("FACEBOOK", "onCompleted");
                        if (user != null)
                        {
                            Log.d("FACEBOOK", "user != null");
                            org.json.JSONObject graphResponse = response.getGraphObject().getInnerJSONObject();
                            String email = graphResponse.optString("email");
                            String id = graphResponse.optString("id");
                            String facebookName = user.getUsername();
                            if (email == null || email.length() < 0)
                            {
                                AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext()).create();
                                alertDialog.setTitle("Facebook Login");
                                alertDialog.setMessage("An email address is required for your account, we could not find an email associated with this Facebook account. Please associate a email with this account.");
                                alertDialog.setButton("Ok",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                        dialog.cancel();
                                    }
                                });
                                alertDialog.show();

                                return;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
                getMe.executeAsync();
            }
            else
            {
                if (!session.isOpened())
                    Log.d("FACEBOOK", "!session.isOpened()");
                else
                    Log.d("FACEBOOK", "isFetching");

            }
        }
    });
}
```

`Log.d("FACEBOOK", "onCompleted");` is never called

I am overriding onActivityResult in my SignUp activity as below, this too never gets called

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    Log.d("FACEBOOK", "onActivityResult");
    Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Comment: Are you overriding the onActivityResult method in your SignUp activity to call Session.getActiveSession.onActivityResult?

Comment: Yes, it too never seems to be called, I have edited my main post to show how I am implementing that.

Comment: I'm having the same problem - did you ever get this resolved?